Managing several Alerts for the same Button while avoiding the deprecated Alert struct and using the instance method instead
Before Alert became deprecated, I used to manage different Alerts of a View by introducing an AlertState:
enum AlertState: Identifiable {
    case associatedIngredient
    case confirmDelete
    
    var id: AlertState { self }
}

I had variable in my View:
@State private var activeAlert: FoodItemViewSheets.AlertState?

which I would set the AlertState with:
// Delete the food item
Button("Delete", systemImage: "trash") {
    if foodItemVM.hasAssociatedFoodItem() {
        // Check if FoodItem is related to an Ingredient
        if !foodItemVM.canBeDeleted() {
            self.activeAlert = .associatedIngredient
        } else {
            self.activeAlert = .confirmDelete
        }
    }
}

... and later:
.alert(item: $activeAlert) {
    alertContent($0)
}

This function would then deliver the right Alert:
private func alertContent(_ state: AlertState) -> Alert {
    switch state {
    case .confirmDelete:
        return Alert(
            title: Text("Delete food"),
            message: Text("Do you really want to delete this food item? This cannot be undone!"),
            primaryButton: .default(
                Text("Do not delete")
            ),
            secondaryButton: .destructive(
                Text("Delete"),
                action: deleteFoodItemOnly
            )
        )
    case .associatedIngredient:
        return Alert(
            title: Text("Cannot delete food"),
            message: Text("This food item is in use in a recipe, please remove it from the recipe before deleting.")
        )
    }
}

As Alert is deprecated, how to get this kind of behavior (two different alerts associated with the same button) to work with the new alert(_:isPresented:presenting:actions:message:) instance method?

There is an init that takes in a LocalizedError

See also Update text inside alert message

You only need one extra @State for passing to the isPresented: parameter. The rest are all pretty self-explanatory. You'd just use switch statements to provide the title, message, and actions as you were already doing. It's just that you are returning View, instead of Alert.
@State private var alertPresented = false
@State private var activeAlert: AlertState?

// this flag controls which alert to show in this toy example
@State private var flag = false

var body: some View {
    // as an example, I will use a toggle to control which alert to show
    Toggle("", isOn: $flag)
    Button("Delete", systemImage: "trash") {
        if flag {
            self.activeAlert = .associatedIngredient
        } else {
            self.activeAlert = .confirmDelete
        }
    }
    .alert(alertTitle, isPresented: $alertPresented, presenting: activeAlert) {
        alertActions(for: $0)
    } message: {
        alertMessage(for: $0)
    }
    .onChange(of: activeAlert) { oldValue, newValue in
        if oldValue == nil && newValue != nil {
            alertPresented = true
        } else if oldValue != nil && newValue == nil {
            alertPresented = false
        }
    }

}

@ViewBuilder
func alertMessage(for alert: AlertState) -> some View {
    switch alert {
    case .associatedIngredient:
        Text("Do you really want to delete this food item? This cannot be undone!")
    case .confirmDelete:
        Text("This food item is in use in a recipe, please remove it from the recipe before deleting.")
    }
}

@ViewBuilder
func alertActions(for alert: AlertState) -> some View {
    switch alert {
    case .associatedIngredient:
        Button("OK", role: .cancel) {}
    case .confirmDelete:
        Button("Do not delete", role: .cancel) { }
        Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

var alertTitle: String {
    switch activeAlert {
    case .associatedIngredient:
        "Cannot delete food"
    case .confirmDelete:
        "Delete food"
    case nil:
        ""
    }
}


Thanks, works great! The only caveat I found is that when using the computed property alertTitle to deliver the title, SwiftUI doesn't treat it a localized string key, so it's not localized. I had to add NSLocalizedString(title, comment: "").

@Ulrich You can just change the type of alertTitle to LocalizedStringKey, and wrap each of the strings in LocalizedStringKey(...).
